# Interface and Inheritance - an Object Oriented Design Dilemma

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I'm having trouble understanding when/why to implement inheritance and when/why to implement inheritance via interface. Please bear with me as I explain..

Let's say we have a parent class `Animal` and we wish to extend it with 3 subclasses: `Dog`, `Cat` and `Mouse`.

Suppose all Animals are able to `eat()`, `sleep()`, `scratch()` and `move()`. and `Dog` is able to `pant()`. With this knowledge we would proceed to add the first 4 behaviors to the `Animal` superclass and have `Dog`, `Cat` and `Mouse` extend `Animal`. We would also add the method `pant()` to the `Dog` class bec only dogs `pant()`.

Now what happens if we wish to add another method called `waggleTail()` but only `Cat` and `Dog` exhibit this behavior. We cannot add this behavior to `Animal` bec then `Mouse` will also inherit the behavior (and Mouse doesn't waggle it's tail). An alternative is to add the method `waggleTail()` to both the `Dog` and the `Cat` classes but not to the `Mouse` class. This approach, however, does not make sense bec we would then violate the DRY principle (don't repeat yourself) by writing the method `waggleTail()` twice. We want to write each method once, and only once.

Perhaps we could solve this problem by creating a new sub class that inherits from `Animal` called `TailWagglingAnimal`, add the method `waggleTail()` to this subclass and then have both `Dog` and `Cat` inherit from this new subclass. This sounds reasonable until you realize that there are dozens of other such anomalies and we'd have to repeat this process again and again for each one (this would expand the inheritance hierarchy to no end).

Further, what if we have a specific kind of `Dog` (let's call him the "Coton de Tulear") that exhibits all of the other behaviors of `Dog` (such as panting) except that it doesn't waggle its tail. If we have "Coton de Tulear" inherit directly from `Animal` it would be unable to pant(). If we had it inherit from `Dog` it would be able to waggle its tail (bec `Dog` extends `TailWagglingAnimal`). If we had `Dog` extend `Animal` directly and then create a new subclass called `TailWagglingDog` (as appose to `TailWagglingAnimal`) then Cat will be unable to inherit this behavior (so we'd need to duplicate the behavior somewhere within the Cat hierarchy which violates the DRY principle).

What do we do?

Based on dozens of threads on stackoverflow (and several OO design books) it has been suggested to remove the method `waggleTail()` from the Dog class and add it to and interface. Let's call the interface  `TailWaggler` and then have all dogs (except for "Coton de Tulear") implement this interface. However, I have trouble understanding why/how this is useful.

If you think about it, this means that all 50+ breads of dogs (let's assume there are 50 breads of Dog that need to exhibit this behavior) need to add the implements `TailWaggler` keyword just bec a single kind of `Dog` does not exhibit this behavior. Not only does this mean a lot of extra manual work on the part of the programmer  (adding implements `TailWaggler`  to the beginning of each class) *it means that all descendants need to be concerned with all of little and petty details of the behavior they exhibit* (this would not be the case had we added this behavior to the parent class and extended the parent class). This may be fine if we only had a few such cases but what if we had dozens or hundreds of such cases? Finally, as we add new types of subclasses of type dogs there will eventually be one kind of `Dog` are another that will not exhibit one of the behaviors of Dog parent class - so this means  slowly but surely we'll need to remove almost all behavior from the (parent) `Dog` class and add them to an interface? We'd then need to make sure all of the sub classes implement dozens of different interfaces. One might suggest that we group all related behavior in a single interface but this is only possible if the behavior exhibited by different dogs is uniform - what if this is not the case?)

Thanks!

Comment: Bear with me. Bear. Bare means naked.

Comment: Using [Mixins](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin) would be one way to solve this problem -- allowing composition and code reuse. However, Java doesn't have native support for Mixins and you would need to work around the problem using delegates or static utilities.

Comment: Perhaps it is better if you provide an actual example from the "complex/abstract" case your dealing with. To me it seems that your Animal, Dog, Cat example may not describe your situation as it is. With the concrete example, we together may be able to come to a solution.

Comment: @MickMnemonic java 8 default interface implementation are a form of Mixins.

Comment: @minus yes, default methods allow for mixins;but when you do some reading you will find that the people behind java do suggest to see them that way.

Answer (score 3):

> We'd then need to make sure all of the sub classes implement dozens of
>   different interfaces

1. If your class needs implementing too many interfaces check that it does not violate the Single Responsibility principle. Consider breaking the class into smaller ones.
2. Implementing several small interfaces instead of a large one conforms to Interface Segregation principle which leads to some positive consequences.

> it means that all descendants need to be concerned with all of little
>   and petty details of the behavior they exhibit

This is more about implementation difficulties. Multiple inheritance or auto delegation could help here. Since we don't have either in Java we have to choose between other options:

1. Implement delegation manually for each class :(
2. Use Java 8 interfaces if implementation is not complicated.
3. Use code generation library to autogenerate delegation code (e.g. look at lombok library @Delegate feature    https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Delegate.html)

Answer (score 2):

Inheritance is used when you want to **morph** a class which is of the same type of your parent class and which have a similar behavior.
Interface is used to declare a **functionality** of your class.

For example, Dogs, Cats and Mice are all Animals (same type) and they have similar behavior (they get born, grow up, die, move, eat, ...). So your Dog class can extend Animal.

Now, your interfaces declare their functions. Like we just seen, an animal can move and eat, so your Animal class can implement the interfaces **Mover** and **Eater** for example. Automatically, Dog, Cat and Mouse will inherit these interfaces, but a mouse will eat cheese while dogs and cats will eat meat. This is where you can `@Override` (understand **morph**) the implementation behavior to declare what each class can eat.

If another animal can climb (a monkey), you will implement the **Climber** interface directly on the Monkey class. Making it slightly more evolved than a standard Animal.

---

For your tailwagging issue, you have to implement the **Tailwagger** interface in Dog and Cat, not in Animal (all animals are not tailwaggers). Of course you do not want to repeat the code, so you will also create another Class called **StandardTailwag** and use it as a field in Dog and Cat (**composition**). You then have to redirect the implementation to this class' methods, but this is the way to go if you want your code easier to maintain in the future.

You could also morph the StandardTailwag to **DogTailwag** and **CatTailwag**, and easily implement them with the same Tailwagger interface

---

Note that you can write *default* code and methods in Java 8's interfaces, but it is not recommended.

Comment: I understand the concept of moving certain functions to an interface - however as I mentioned in the OP the primary issue with this is that somewhere down the line one of the descendants will not need most of functionality of the parent class (Animal) which will prevent us from implementing the interface in the Animal class and force us to implement the interface in each one of the child classes. This brings us back to the problem I mentioned that each of the child classes will need to be concerned with exactly what interface(s) they will implement.

Comment: I don't know your code, but you can always annotate the Class to specify special behaviors. Runtime annotations are your friends.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very broad and subjective question, so I can give you my opinion and no more.

My personal principle is: "The less code you write, the better", but to be truthful achieving simplicity is exceedingly difficult.

I try to make inheritance as shallow as I can, because deep inheritance tends to become a problem later on when your model changes.

I then use interface with *handlers* so instead of having a method waggleTail I have a stateless TailWaggler class which does the waggling thing.

I don't think there is a recipe for every possible situation, I try keep it as simple as I can, as testable as possible, then you will have (sooner or  later) to refactor your code, if test are good, it will not be too painful.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer to a long question, so don't accept this until others that have more energy chime in.  BUT how I would do that would be to have an abstract Dog class that implements the TailWagger interface, and has a concrete tailWag function.

Next have all your dogs inherit from Dog, including the one that doesn't actually wag.  Then in that particular dog implementation, create a new concrete function called tailWag that throws an exception along the lines of InvalidStateException("This type of dog does not wag its tail") .

Using this methodology, you have one concrete "tailWag" that wags the tail, and one exceptional case that behaves differently.

Comment: That would be a violation of LSP, because the one will not be able to use ParticularDog (subtype) in place of Dog (supertype) without changing program's behaviour.

Comment: Then do something else.  Sheesh, it was just meant to be an idea.  You'll note there's no code attached...